# How to load address of function or label into register

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

I am trying to load the address of 'main' into a register (R10) in the GNU Assembler. I am unable to. Here I what I have and the error message I receive.

```
main:
   lea main, %r10
```

I also tried the following syntax (this time using mov)

```
main:
   movq $main, %r10
```

With both of the above I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxZ8pWr.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `main' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiling with -fPIC does not resolve the issue and just gives me the same exact error.

Comment: Use an rip-relative addressing mode: `lea main(%rip), %r10`

Comment: This could be marked as a duplicate, but this is nicely written as a good place for a canonical answer about putting static addresses into registers.  I've written that as part of other answers many times, now I can just link here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In x86-64, most immediates and displacements are still 32-bits because 64-bit would waste too much code size (I-cache footprint and fetch/decode bandwidth).

`lea main, %reg` is an absolute `disp32` addressing mode which would stop load-time address randomization (ASLR) from choosing a random 64-bit (or 47-bit) address.  So [it's not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) on Linux except in position-dependent executables, or at all on MacOS where static code/data are always loaded outside the low 32 bits.  (See the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to docs and guides.)  On Windows, you can build executables as "large address aware" or not.  If you choose not, addresses will fit in 32 bits.

---

The standard efficient way to put a static address into a register is **a RIP-relative LEA**:

```asm
# RIP-relative LEA always works.  Syntax for various assemblers:
  lea main(%rip), %r10       # AT&T syntax

  lea  r10, [rip+main]       # GAS .intel_syntax noprefix   equivalent
  lea  r10, [rel main]       ; NASM equivalent, or use  default rel
  lea  r10, [main]           ; FASM defaults to RIP-relative.  MASM may also
```

See [How do RIP-relative variable references like "[RIP + _a]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy) for an explanation of the 3 syntaxes, and [Why are global variables in x86-64 accessed relative to the instruction pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262889/why-are-global-variables-in-x86-64-accessed-relative-to-the-instruction-pointer) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing)) for reasons why RIP-relative is the standard way to address static data.

This uses a 32-bit relative displacement from the end of the current instruction, like `jmp`/`call`.  This can reach any static data in `.data`, `.bss`, `.rodata`, or function in `.text`, assuming the usual 2GiB total size limit for static code+data.

---

In position *dependent* code (built with `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie` for example) on Linux, you *can* take advantage of 32-bit absolute addressing to save code size.  Also, `mov r32, imm32` has slightly better throughput than RIP-relative LEA on Intel/AMD CPUs, so out-of-order execution may be able to overlap it better with the surrounding code.  (Optimizing for code-size is usually less important than most other things, but when all else is equal pick the shorter instruction.  In this case all else *is* at least equal, or also better with `mov imm32`.)

See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) for more about how PIE executables are the default. (Which is why you got a link error about `-fPIC` with your use of a 32-bit absolute.)

```asm
# in a non-PIE executable,  mov imm32 into a 32-bit register is even better
# same as you'd use in 32-bit code
## GAS AT&T syntax
mov  $main, %r10d        # 6 bytes
mov  $main, %edi         # 5 bytes: no REX prefix needed for a "legacy" register

## GAS .intel_syntax
mov  edi, OFFSET main

;;  mov  edi, main     ; NASM and FASM syntax
```

Note that writing any 32-bit register *always* zero-extends into the full 64-bit register (R10 and RDI).

`lea main, %edi` or `lea main, %rdi` would also work in a Linux non-PIE executable, but never use LEA with a `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode (even in 32-bit code where that doesn't require a SIB byte); `mov` is always at least as good.

The operand-size suffix is redundant when you have a register operand that uniquely determines it; I prefer to just write `mov` instead of `movl` or `movq`.

---

The stupid/bad way is a 10-byte 64-bit absolute address as an immediate:

```asm
# Inefficient, DON'T USE
movabs  $main, %r10            # 10 bytes including the 64-bit absolute address
```

This is what you get in NASM if you use `mov  rdi, main` instead of `mov edi, main` so many people end up doing this.  Linux dynamic linking *does* actually support runtime fixups for 64-bit absolute addresses.  But the use-case for that is for jump tables, not for absolute addresses as immediates.

---

`movq $sign_extended_imm32, %reg` (7 bytes) still uses a 32-bit absolute address, but wastes code bytes on a sign-extended `mov` to a 64-bit register, instead of implicit zero-extension to 64-bit from writing a 32-bit register.

By using `movq`, you're telling GAS you *want* a `R_X86_64_32S` relocation instead of a `R_X86_64_64` 64-bit absolute relocation.

The only reason you'd ever want this encoding is for kernel code where static addresses are in the upper 2GiB of 64-bit virtual address space, instead of the lower 2GiB.  `mov` has *slight* performance advantages over `lea` on some CPUs (e.g. running on more ports), but normally if you can use a 32-bit absolute it's in the low 2GiB of virtual address space where a `mov r32, imm32` works.

(Related: [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64))

---

PS: I intentionally left out any discussion of "large" or "huge" memory / code models, where RIP-relative +-2GiB addressing can't reach static data, or maybe can't even reach other code addresses.  The above is for x86-64 System V ABI's "small" and/or "small-PIC" code models.  You may need `movabs $imm64` for medium and large models, but that's very rare.

I don't know if `mov $imm32, %r32` works in Windows x64 executables or DLLs with runtime fixups, but RIP-relative LEA certainly does.

Semi-related: [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code) - if you're JITing, try to put the JIT buffer near existing code so you can `call rel32`, otherwise `movabs` a pointer into a register.

Comment: The return of memory models.

Comment: @ecm: I've seen like 1 or 2 questions ever on Stack Overflow that mentioned needing to use a "large-data" code model for something, in the tags I follow (x86*, assembly, and a few related ones).  I think it was Fortran with huge static arrays.  But yes, interesting point that the 32-bit x86 GNU/Linux ABI was blissfully free of different sizes of memory model / code model.  The i386 SysV ABI doc only mentions "code model" once in something that might have been copied from x86-64.  But with rel32 displacements for 64-bit address space, AMD64 does create room for choice.